# How to trigger mail from email directus schedule cron job in hooks- directus-9.24

Tags: javascript, linux, nodemailer, directus, directus-flows

In Hooks we have the option to run   scheduled cron jobs, so I want to use mail services here, how to get the mailService here?

1. tried to pass the mail service  I  schedule parameter is not taking, so I don't know where I need to get the mail services

```
export default ({ schedule }) => {
    schedule('*/15 * * * *', async () => {
await mailService.send({
                from: payload.email,,
                to: payload.email,
                cc:payload.email, ,
                subject: subject,
                template: {
                    name: ,
                    data: payload,
                },
            });
    });
};
```